# Get JSON "current name/object"?

Tags: php, json

Let's say the JSON looks like this:

```
"response":{
    "success":1,
    "inventory":{
        "apples" { "count": 1 },
        "bananas" { "count": 53 },
        etc
```

Then I have a PHP file that reads it like this:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(JSON URL));
foreach($json->response->inventory as $item)
{
     echo $item->count; // would count 1 then 53
}
?>
```

How do I read the current "directory" (I have no idea what it is called) that I am in? As in how do I echo out "apples", "bananas" etc, depending on which one I'm foreach'ing.

I tried just printing out $item, but doesn't show anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `foreach` syntax covers this with the `=>` operator:

```
foreach ($json->response->inventory as $fruit => $item)
```

Comment: So that would let me use $fruit as the "directory", and $item as I did in my question?

Comment: @MathiasSjöberg yes, and this is typically called the `key` or `property name` (or just `property`) among other things depending on the context and language.

Comment: Thank you, Explosion Pills!